# Android Google Places autocomplete api bounds not working

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I want to be able to autocomplete some places by using the google places api. I only want to include certain places from a certain area. Googles API docs describe this feature by using the function `setBoundsBias`, but I can't seem to get it working properly as it still returns results from outside the specified area.

```
try {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
                            new LatLng(16.371163, 21.051073),
                            new LatLng(16.725743, 21.424006)))
                    .build(getActivity());

            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How are you using the LatLngBounds? It states in the documentation that they should be top-left and bottom-right respectively.

`A LatLngBounds object that defines a geographical area using two sets of latitude/longitude coordinates marking the top left and bottom right corners.`

Comment: I looked through the source code in android studio and the first param seems to be southwest and the second one northeast. Will try to switch them

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, I just tried with the exact same and it's working for me. I confirm it's southWest first and then NorthEast, otherwise an exception is raised. One thing strange though : I can still see some results outside from my BoundBias, for exemple if I write another city name. However if I just 3 or 4 letters, all my results belong to the bias. If I remove the Bounds, then I have tons of results outside.

Comment: @RaphaëlTitol maybe this just kinda depends on where you live then, as I can see alot of other places from outside the bounds, even if I wrote the full name. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @qwertz its not working for me. I did exactly the same. You found any solution?

Comment: The german version of https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#restrict_autocomplete_results says that results within the bounds are PREFERRED. So it seems okay that there are still results from outside the bounds. I believe it is the right/intended behaviour. :(

Answer (score 0):

The `setBoundsBias` is supposed to return results from outside the area.
It is only a bias.
If you want to exclusively return results from within the bounds, you must use the `AutocompleteFilter`.
Unfortunately currently the only level of filtering by region is by country.